# In RPG, use a date, in *job format from a file

Tags: date, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I'm trying to convert, in a RPG program, a date from a file (it's from the DSPJRN command, so the field si 6 numeric, in JOB format).
I want to use it as a date in my program, but I can't achieve it correctly.

I have tried to describe a field with type "D": date, keyword datfmt(*job) to convert the value from the file, but datfmt(*job) is incorrect (error RNF0612)

I have tried to retrieve the job Date format from a CLP program with RTVJOBA DATFMT(&FMT), and use the variable in RPG to convert the date like this

`eval      ztJODATE = %date(JODATE:FMT)`

but it doesn't compile : error RNF0606 . I think that I can't use a variable for the format in the %date built-in function.

Is this a way to do what I want, or am I forced to transform the date value in SQL before using its value in RPG?
PS: I don't want to hardcode the format in my RPG program!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify *JOBRUN for %DATE.

```
eval      ztJODATE = %date(JODATE:*JOBRUN)
```

Note that RPG retrieves the job date format during initialization of the module, so if you change the job date format while the program is running, RPG will not understand the date.

Comment: Yep! That was what I was searching... I must have seen the option, and tried it with no luck, so I thought it wasn't the good format... But it was just that DSPJRN created a char field for the date... If I do ```ztJODATE = %date(JODATE:*JOBRUN)``` it gives an error, but if I do ```ztJODATE = %date(%int(JODATE):*JOBRUN)```it works!

Comment: What error does it give if you just do %date(JODATE:*JOBRUN)? Is it a compile-time error or a runtime error? What is the datatype of JODATE?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using DSPJRN to an outfile, the recommended way to retrieve and process journal entries would be to use one of the programatic interfaces provided by IBM i.

- [Retrieve Journal Entries (QjoRetrieveJournalEntries) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/QJORJRNE.htm)
- [QSYS2.DISPLAY_JOURNAL() stored procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1136710)

You could also use a *TYPE3 or higher format for the output file.  Rather than the separate job formatted data & time fields, there's a single char(26) system timestamp field.

Having said that, there is a [Convert Date and Time Format (QWCCVTDT) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qwccvtdt.htm) that accepts `'*JOB'` as an input format specifier..

Comment: Thanks, I've use QWCCVDT for now (which is a bit strange: have to add a century to a value in an input format without century, and gives a result that is not a date, not a timestamp, but have to be modified to be converted in a timestamp). I red the other informations you gave, so the next time I'll want to use journal infos (or if I'll make lots of change in this programs), I'll think to use the stored procedure...